# Destiny "Focused Fire" weapon mod, does it balance out?

Tags: destiny

The weapon upgrade mod "Focused Fire", what's the exact mechanics for this?

The description reads:

> **Focused Fire**
>   When zoomed, this weapon fires slower, but deals additional damage.

With this icon:

[image: Focused Fire Icon]

Does the reduced rate of fire and the increased damage balance out?

Meaning, will aiming down the sights do the same DPS as when not aiming, provided you hit every shot the same place?

I know there are things like more control over recoil with reduced rate of fire, but other than that?

As an example of numbers that would balance out:

- Not aiming: 100 damage per bullet, 10 rounds per second, total **1000 dps**
- Focused Fire: 50% firing rate, 2x damage per bullet
- Aiming: 200 damage per bullet, 5 rounds per second, total **1000 dps**

Is the exact firing rate reduction and damage increase known?

Comment: I haven't checked exact numbers, but I find that I drop enemies faster with Focused Fire activated. It also (and perhaps more importantly) makes the recoil more controllable.

Comment: Yes, I feel the same way, but I have not tested the numbers either. I got the mod on the [Suros Regime](http://www.destinypedia.com/Suros_Regime) exotic weapon, but I did not write down damage numbers or recorded a video so I could see the difference. It could be that the more controllable recoil is what makes me better at firing with it than before the mod was unlocked, but it could also mean that the increased damage per bullet overcompensates for the reduced rate of fire so that it actually does more damage now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** it balances out.

After running some experiments before and after applying the upgrade, it makes your weapon do 130% damage (with some apparent rounding errors in the integer calculations). Over the same period of time it does the same damage as before, but uses less bullets to do it.